# Using Jenkins declarative when conditions in scripted pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

Jenkins declarative pipelines offer very convenient **when** directive with conditions like **changeset**.

Is is possible the this changeset and other when conditions in a scripted pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem not - in the scripted pipeline, groovy needs to be used - see [the docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control)

```java
node {
    stage('Example') {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
        } else {
            echo 'I execute elsewhere'
        }
    }
}
```

(taken straight from the docs)

This would be the same as `when { branch 'master' }`

Comment: Thanks Bruce for sharing this. Well, it is obvious that one can write a code which behaves like when conditions, however both when statement and its conditions are written in java (or maybe even groovy) and, I believe, should be available from a groovy pipeline as well.

Comment: @mangolier Those built-in keywords like `stage` and `node` are called steps. You can see all the steps available for a scripted pipeline on this page https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ . There is no `when` step.